# TensorFlow 2.1 - TypeError: padded_batch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'padded_shapes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to replicate https://keras.io/examples/vision/retinanet/ tutorial on my Local environment where I have CUDA. But, since I am using Windows, TensorFlow version is 2.1, not 2.4. In documentation (TensorFlow 2.4 version) for which this tutorial was intended, `padded_shapes` seems to be OPTIONAL argument, while in TensorFlow 2.1. version it is required. How do I avoid this or how do I set it to right value?

Here is the code:

```
autotune = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(preprocess_data, num_parallel_calls=autotune)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(8 * batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(
    batch_size=batch_size, padding_values=(0.0, 1e-8, -1), drop_remainder=True
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    label_encoder.encode_batch, num_parallel_calls=autotune
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(autotune)

val_dataset = val_dataset.map(preprocess_data, num_parallel_calls=autotune)
val_dataset = val_dataset.padded_batch(
    batch_size=1, padding_values=(0.0, 1e-8, -1), drop_remainder=True
)
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(label_encoder.encode_batch, num_parallel_calls=autotune)
val_dataset = val_dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
val_dataset = val_dataset.prefetch(autotune)
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-363-22fc45aaf608> in <module>
      3 train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(8 * batch_size)
      4 train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(
----> 5     batch_size=batch_size, padding_values=(0.0, 1e-8, -1), drop_remainder=True
      6 )
      7 train_dataset = train_dataset.map(

TypeError: padded_batch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'padded_shapes'
```

Comment: Have I answered your question or something left unclear?

Answer (score 0):

[v2.1 method](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) have different signature compared to [v2.4 method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch)
Solutions:

1. update to [v2.2+](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.2/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch)
2. try: `val_dataset = val_dataset.padded_batch( batch_size=1, padded_shapes=[None], padding_values=(0.0, 1e-8, -1), drop_remainder=True)`